# Changing texture of an object in runtime

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to make a GUI button that changes the texture of a GameObject... Any ideas?

I made this code, but the sphere turns white, it doesn't show texture

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Vuforia
{
    public class GUI_Button : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        GameObject Pokeball;
        Texture3D texture = (Texture3D) Resources.Load ("Resources/clouds1024");

        private void OnGUI() 
        {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (5, 15, 100, 25), "Pokeball")) {
                Pokeball = GameObject.Find("Pokeball");

                Pokeball.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you try to use it?

Comment: I can't catch the 'sphere.renderer.material'...

Comment: if `sphere` is a `GameObject` then you do `sphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = runtimeMaterial;`

Comment: There's a error about the Material, I'm not using it. There's a way to apply texture directly on sphere?

Comment: what does the error say, and yes you just drag the material onto the sphere

Comment: I tried this: Pokeball.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture(1, texture); doesn't works =(

Comment: Yea but you said theres an error whats the error? Because saying doesnt work really isnt saying much

Comment: I will edit my question and put my code.. The problem now it is that the sphere turns white and don't catch the reference about the texture

Comment: check if `texture` varaible is null or not , use  `Debug.log(texture+"")` and check the output